# Finding latest successful logins and failed attempts to a CentOS server

Tags: linux, security, centos

I'm looking for a log file or any service to report the latest login attempts that have failed due to username/password mismatch. Are there any such utilities available for CentOS? (built-in is preferred)

My second question, and more generally, I need a log file of penetration attempts to my server. Ideally, this log should contain all attempts including logins, httpd activities, and other conventional open ports.

Comment: answer to second question: take a look at [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/).

Comment: This thread is moved from Stackoverflow after I asked the question in Serverfault. [Here](http://serverfault.com/questions/430878/reporting-penetration-attempts-to-my-server/430881#430881) is the threads discussing the second question.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In Linux, the `last` command shows successful login attempts and displays session information (pts, source, date and length).

The `lastb` command records all bad login attempts. Both share the same `man` page, but the difference is that `last` reads the binary `/var/log/wtmp` file, and `lastb` reads the `/var/log/btmp` file by default.

The range of these files depends on your log rotation schedule, but it should span a few weeks. Most distributions will rotate `/var/log/wtmp` monthly, so you can read a previous record, usually listed as `/var/log/wtmp.1` by specifying the file with the `-f` parameter... `last -f /var/log/wtmp.1`

Answer (score 14):

The question is here offtopic, but a very short answer: maybe you should just check /var/log/secure (e.g. grep for "failed").

Comment: It is actually the answer to my first question. I'll ask the second in ServerFault. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a old thread but I got similar task like this,so in my case this is a log entry

```
Nov 15 17:14:47 megatron sshd[4768]: Failed password for git from 192.168.122.1 port 49227 ssh2
```

So we can do it like this,if we are sure user is static

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG=/var/log/secure
MESSAGE="Failed password for git"
grep -i "$MESSAGE" "$LOG
```

In case if we know on the per user basis

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG=/var/log/secure
if [ -n "$1" ]
then
NEWUSER="$1"
else
NEWUSER="root"
fi
MESSAGE="Failed password for $NEWUSER"
grep -i "$MESSAGE" "$LOG"
```

So script should execute like

```
[root@megatron bash1]# ./failedlogin.sh git
```

OR more easier approach

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG=/var/log/secure
MESSAGE="Failed password for"
grep -i "$MESSAGE" "$LOG"
```